# Extract nth column from a variable

Tags: bash, shell

i have a variable `Firstline` with value `FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,1153,,0000000801,W` from which i need `5th` field alone.

Can any one help me to resolve this.

I have used the below command but it is giving me an error

`echo "FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,1153,,0000000801,W" | awk -f ',' '{print $5}'`

`awk: fatal: can't open source file`
`,' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: not an awk guy but it looks like -f is to specify an input file. Looks like you'll have to read the docs on this one.

Comment: you want `-F,` not `-f`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-F` not `-f`.

`-F` is for the field separator

`-f` is for the filename of the awk program.

Answer (score 2):

As you tag it as `bash` and not `awk` (which is also a valid solution), you can do

```
IFS=, read -a a <<< "FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,1153,,0000000801,W"
echo ${a[4]}
```

to obtain the same result without spawning a new process (note that bash arrays are 0-based).

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed too

```
echo "..." | sed -E 's/([^,]*,){4}([^,]*).*/\2/'
```